# Update statement in a trigger or a scheduled job in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I want to update certain rows if the status of a device is changed. Here is the plain update statement:

```
update REMINDER set FLAG_LIST = 0 where ID in 
(select r.id from REMINDER r 
    join DEVICE d
        on d.id = (regexp_replace(r.origin_values, '[^0-9]', ''))         
        and d.status <> 0
        and r.context = 'DEVICE'
        and r.flag_list <> 0);
```

I wrote a trigger like below but I get an ORA-04091 (table DEVICE is mutating, trigger/function may not see ist) when i change the status of a device:

```
create or replace TRIGGER DEACTIVATE_REMINDER 
AFTER UPDATE OF STATUS ON DEVICE 
for each row
BEGIN
if updating then
    if (:old.STATUS = 0 and :new.STATUS != 0) then
        update REMINDER set FLAG_LIST = 0 where ID in 
            (select r.ID from REMINDER r 
                join DEVICE d
                    on d.id = (regexp_replace(r.ORIGIN_VALUES, '[^0-9]', ''))         
                    and d.STATUS <> 0
                    and d.ID = :new.ID
                    and r.CONTEXT = 'DEVICE'
                    and r.FLAG_LIST <> 0);
    end if;
end if;
END;
```

Maybe i can not use a trigger here, because the same object whose modification triggered the trigger must not be modified or read in a row-level trigger? Is it better to use a scheduled job somehow?

What I also want to do is to update the `FLAG_LIST` back to `1`, if the `STATUS` of a device is changed back to `0`. The only way i can imagine to do this is also in the trigger, but as i wrote I`m not sure if this is basically possible.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A row-level trigger on `device` can't query the `device` table.  My wager, though, is that you don't need to and can simply use the `:new` pseudorecord (note that the `:new.status` predicate in the subquery is redundant here given the `if` statement but doesn't hurt anything)

```
create or replace TRIGGER DEACTIVATE_REMINDER 
  AFTER UPDATE OF STATUS ON DEVICE 
  for each row
BEGIN
if updating then
    if (:old.STATUS = 0 and :new.STATUS != 0) then
        update REMINDER set FLAG_LIST = 0 where ID in 
            (select r.ID 
               from REMINDER r 
              where :new.id = (regexp_replace(r.ORIGIN_VALUES, '[^0-9]', ''))         
                and :new.STATUS <> 0
                and r.CONTEXT = 'DEVICE'
                and r.FLAG_LIST <> 0);
    end if;
end if;
END;
```

If that's not what you want, it would be helpful to provide a full test case that we can run to see the behavior you want.  You could create a compound trigger with a row-level component that stores the modified `id` values in a collection and then a statement-level component that updates the table using that collection.  But that seems like overkill in this situation.

Architecturally, however, I am always **really** hesitant about designs that put this sort of logic in triggers.  It will virtually always make more sense to have a stored procedure that updates the `device` table and then runs whatever update you want on the `reminder` table.  You won't need to be concerned about a mutating table exception, all the logic will be in one place rather than partially in an application and partially in a trigger, you won't encounter problems if two months from now you want to create a trigger on the `reminder` table that involves queries against `device`, etc.

Comment: After i integrated your code into the trigger, the trigger works as intended. I can also switch the `FLAG_LIST` value fitting to the status with a second if-clause.

Comment: But your doubts about the general architecture are reasonable. My problem after the first considerations about the procedure is, that I do not know where/how to call it.

Comment: @schmimla - You'd call the procedure instead of putting the `update device` statement in your code.  So rather than having an `update device ...` statement, you'd, say, call the `update_device_status` procedure which would take care of any updates that were required on the `reminder` table.